# Set command alias for print in python?

Tags: python, aliases

In bash you can give a command an alias like so:

```
alias e=echoset 
alias e="echo blah"
```

I want to know how to do the same thing in Python.  I know you can give classes aliases, but when I try to give a command (the print statement for example) an alias, I get an error:

```
>>> p = print
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    p = print
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I can do this:

```
p = "print"
exec(p)
```

But that isn't really the same thing as aliasing, and I can't give any input to the command.

**Update:**
@atzz You guessed right, it is not specific to print.  What I am trying to get to work is this:

This is supposed to set the command, but instead, it just beeps when I enter this:
    `>>> beep = Popen(['play', '-q', '/home/Username/Mich/Sound Effects/Beeps/beep-17-short.ogg'])`

Then when I enter beep into the prompt, it shows this:
    `>>> beep 
    <subprocess.Popen object at 0x9967b8c>`

But other then this problem I have, at least now I know that you can't give statements aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your new question, if you want to do this and have beep execute later:

```
beep = Popen(['play', '-q', '/home/Username/Mich/Sound Effects/Beeps/beep-17-short.ogg'])
```

Change it to:

```
beep = lambda: Popen(['play', '-q', '/home/Username/Mich/Sound Effects/Beeps/beep-17-short.ogg'])
```

Or just a function :-)

```
def beep(): Popen(['play', '-q', '/home/Username/Mich/Sound Effects/Beeps/beep-17-short.ogg'])
```

Otherwise 'beep' will just hold the return value of Popen.

Answer (score 9):

Is your question specific to `print`?

In Python prior to 3.0, `print` is a keyword in the language grammar. Since it's not a first-class language object, you cannot assign it to a variable.

In Python 3.0, there is no keyword `print`; there's a `print` function instead ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print)).

With an appropriate future statement, you can use the print function in Python 2.6+:

```
from __future__ import print_function
a = print
a("Hello!")
```

Comment: @gnibbler - Thanks for the correction. I "knew" it appeared in 2.7 so I even missed the contrary info in the doc I linked to :)

Answer (score 7):

It's only the print statement you'll have this problem with, because it's a statement (like while/if/etc.) rather than a function.

If you wanted to 'rename' (for instance) len, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is exactly why Python 3 took place. In PY3 `print` is a function, not keyword, and yes, you can do it there.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason why Py3 took place, but the rest is correct :-)

Comment: Indeed :-) That is one of the reasons.